# How to use tags in Simatic WinCC Flexible VB script

Tags: sql-server, automation

I am trying to insert some Wincc tags value into a SQL server. for this I firstly defined an sql connection and I've tested inserting rough values with a simple SQL tag like:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (T1,T2) Values (3,4)"
```

I saw that I can use variables in this SQL cmd

```
const d = 5
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (T1,T2) Values (" & d & ",4)"
```

how should I use Wincc Tags instead of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

I can share with you some code I used with WinCC flexible 2008 to insert into a database a simple record afeter any recipe finished by the plant.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
Dim sServer,sDataBaseName ,sConn,oConn,oRS, FetchData
Dim sUserName,sPassWord
Dim adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
Dim mRecordstr, tableName
Dim field


Dim loc_PRESSURE
Dim loc_ENDDATETIME
Dim loc_RECEIPE
Dim loc_BEGINDATETIME
Dim loc_USER
Dim loc_TEMPERATURE

loc_USER = SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_USER")
loc_BEGINDATETIME = CDate(SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_BEGINDATETIME"))
loc_ENDDATETIME = CDate(SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_ENDDATETIME"))
loc_RECEIPE = SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_RECEIPE")
loc_PRESSURE = SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_PRESSURE")
loc_TEMPERATURE = SmartTags("DatabaseSQL\var_TEMPERATURE")



sServer = "192.168.40.3" 'e.g
sDataBaseName = "DBPLC"
sUserName = "USER"'INSERT USER NAME ENABLED IN DATABASE
sPassWord = "SECRETPASSWORD" '
tableName = "TABLE_PLC"

adOpenKeyset = 1
adLockOptimistic = 3
adCmdTable = 2

sConn="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" & sServer & ";DATABASE=" & sDataBaseName & ";Encrypt=NO;"
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.CommandTimeout = 36000
oConn.Open sConn, sUserName, sPassWord


Set FetchData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'FetchData.open "SELECT * FROM TABLE_PLC", oConn, 3
FetchData.Open tableName, oConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

FetchData.AddNew

FetchData.Fields("USER").Value = loc_USER
FetchData.Fields("BEGINDATETIME").Value = loc_BEGINDATETIME
FetchData.Fields("ENDDATETIME").Value  = loc_ENDDATETIME
FetchData.Fields("RECEIPE").Value  = loc_RECEIPE
FetchData.Fields("PRESSURE").Value  = loc_PRESSURE
FetchData.Fields("TEMPERATURE").Value  = loc_TEMPERATURE


FetchData.Update

FetchData.Close
oConn.Close
```

Comment: The WinCC Tags in my case are saved under a folder called "DatabaseSQL".

Answer (score -1):

Try to use parameterized SQL query with parameters and write your variables into this parameters. And check data type of your variables and data fields in sql table - it must be the same. It's the only possible way to solve your problem.

It's C++ example:

```
ADOQuery1->SQL->Add("INSERT INTO Your_table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8) VALUES (:param1,'"+Name_text->Text+"', '"+Type_text->Text+"', :param5, :param4, :param3, :param2, '"+Comment_text->Text+"')");
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("param5")->Value= StrToFloat(edit1_text->Text);
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("param4")->Value= StrToFloat(edit2_text->Text);
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("param3")->Value= StrToFloat(edit3_text->Text);
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("param2")->Value= StrToFloat(edit4_text->Text);
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("param1")->Value= StrToInt(edit5_text->Text);
ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();
```

You can rewrite something like this on VBS.

Look also here (it seems like vbs code):
[How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)